# Azure SSIS Deploying in SQL Azure

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, etl, azure, azure-data-factory

Does deploying SSIS really required an azure data lake house when deploying on Azure database?. I am currently working on an SSIS project that its database is currently deployed on Azure and I am currently having an issue deploying it because it sends me directly in the "Integration Services Project or Packages" page and having this I think will require me to turn on Azure Data Lake Storage and this will cost us. is there anyway that I can deploy an SSIS package for free?

Answer (score 1):

You will incur some expenses if you want to run ETLs (packages) from Azure. You can create Integration runtime via Azure Data factory and deploy package to the SSIS catalogue for Azure sql database.

[Createing Azure SSIS Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime)